# How can I access element properties from an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have the follow HTML code:

```
<form ng-submit="login()" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="email" 
                    class="input-large text-field-gra" 
                    ng-model="email"
                    maxlength="50"
                    required 
                    placeholder="<?php echo __('E-mail') ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="password" 
                    class="input-large text-field-gra" 
                    ng-model="password"
                    minlength="4"
                    maxlength="10"
                    required 
                    placeholder="<?php echo __('Senha') ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-default-rb btn-large center-block">
                    <?php echo __('Entrar') ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I have the follow controller fragment:

```
usersApp.controller('userApp.controller', [ '$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location ) {

        var base = document.getElementById('local_url').href;

        $scope.login = function() {

            //This code is the problem
             var e = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#email' ) );
             e = $(scope.$element);


            if( e.hasClass( 'ng-invalid-email' ) ) {
                bootbox.alert( 'O e-mail digitado é inválido' );//This e-mail is invalid.
                return;
            }
         ....
```

I want to know if the element has a class (in this cas ng-invalid-email), but I don't know how I could do it.

I cannot use the default validation, I need to show the message and the controller works without this validation.

Could you help-me.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use [angular form validation directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and disable your submit button while your form is invalid.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-default-rb btn-large center-block">
```

Here is a fiddle with your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/4dt3mruq/28/

Comment: This is possible, but we need to keep the behavior from the system, and the rest of the system show messages to validate the fields.